# symfony passing variable from action to template

Tags: php, templates, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sizeof

**action:**

```
$photos = Doctrine::getTable('photo')
             ->createQuery('u')
            ->addWhere('status = ?', 1)
            ->addOrderBy('sort_order DESC')
            ->execute();
var_dump(sizeof($photos)); //returned 0
$this->photos = $photos
```

**template:**

```
var_dump($sizeof($photos)); // returned 1
```

When I have nothing in the table, its strange that the two above var_dump returned 0 and 1 respectively.

If i have one row record in the table, it will both return 1.

Anyone knows whats going wrong with my code?

Comment: var_dump($sizeof($photos)); // returned 1; 
is that a type before sizeof the '$' or it's intended

Comment: @jingpe you should use 4 spaces to indent your code instead of `>` which is for quoted text.

Comment: could you try and var_dump the actual results from action and template in order to compare. It may be something because of the template decorator

Answer (score 0):

if in the template you use

```
$photos->count()
```

it should give you the right value.